# background check of my to be employer

Tags: resignation, references, background-check

I have resigned two days back in my current organisation because i got the offer from my dream company. I have joining after 3 months. Now here is the thing, I have heard that my current employer (say C1) has some legal issues with my future employer (say C2). And I know that C2 has a very hard background check process. C2 has clearly mentioned that in case of background check failure I will be terminated without any prior notice. NOW I have a feeling that when C2 will contact C1 for my background check C1 might end up giving negative review about me. But can this happen? Should I convince C2 for not contacting in this case(but they might take it in a negative way)

What should I do?
Whom should I talk about this?

Comment: Background check and references are not the same

Comment: We can't tell you what to do, *what do you want to do*? Warn the new company about the potential for a bad reference? As Frisbee said, a background check is not at all the same as a reference check. To note: don't ever resign when you have a job offer contingent on a background check as they *can* fall through.

Comment: If you haven't lied on your resume, and if you've told them that you worked for company C1 then you should be fine. A negative reference would be a stumbling block, but I think they would understand given the circumstances.

Answer (score 5):

Do nothing. As @Frisbee said, background check and reference check are different thngs. Unless they have proof of criminal behavior on your part, nothing they will say will adversely affect you -- and if they flat-out lie, you sue them for character defamation, so unless they're suicidal that's really not likely.